# Using a MOSFET to switch a High Voltage on a Capacitive Load

Tags: voltage, mosfet, switches

I am trying to bias the filament of an electron gun to -575 V, but I need to switch it on and off using a TTL signal. I have an idea for how to do it, but I would like to know if it will work before I start messing with HV power supplies. My question is will this circuit switch the voltage? If not, how can I improve it or what would work better? (EDITED to fix MOSFET orientation.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTYmE7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The data sheet for the MOSFET may be found here: http://ixapps.ixys.com/Datasheet/DS99988B%28IXTH-T16P60P%29.pdf

Comment: What magnitude of capacitance are you talking about? How fast do you expect to be able to switch it? And you have the connections of your P-channel MOSFET backwards. The source needs to be connected to ground.

Comment: As Dave noted, you've got the source and drain terminals backwards, but it also won't work because you need to drive the gate negative with respect to GND in order to turn the MOSFET on.

Comment: @Dave Tweed I'm not sure what the capacitance is, in fact, I'm no longer so sure that it is entirely capacitive. I inherited this project and I was going off what notes had been left to me, but now I think the load does draw a very small current (~10 microAmps).

Comment: @EM Fields The gate does go negative with respect to ground because the inverter makes the TTL go between 0 and -5 V. Or am I misunderstanding your concern?

Comment: @DaveTweed While I still do not know the capacitance, the load was driven in a low voltage (~-80 V) version of the circuit by a 2N4403 BJT sufficiently fast with a resistor at R3 of 560 Ohms.

Comment: @Wells: Ah. Sorry 'bout that, the opamp circuit had a spooky look about it since no negative supply connection was shown.

Comment: Well, there's no galvanic isolation between the high voltage and your low voltage circuitry, so there is a considerable safety concern.  MOSFETS often fail with the gate shorted to the body, and that could potentially put high voltage on your input circuitry.  If this is a product for sale there are regulations about how to handle high voltage.  Otherwise you just need to take appropriate safety measures.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few different issues/comments I see with this.

1. That's a 600V MOSFET and you're planning on using it at 575V. I'd say use a >= 900V MOSFET to be safe.
2. You show an inverting op-amp to get a negative voltage, but it isn't clear at all that you have a negative voltage supply (e.g. -10V). If you don't have that negative supply, your circuit will not work.
3. You probably want to drive the MOSFET with a decent on voltage, like -10V or more. Note that the RDS(on) is specified at a Vgs of -10V. That transistor is barely on at -5V. That means your inverting amplifier should have a gain of -4 or so from a TTL output (2.6V).
4. Some Op-amps don't like driving a capacitive load (like a MOSFET gate)
5. You may want a gate resistor
6. This will not switch the MOSFET quickly, but I don't see that as an issue as long as you aren't switching the power on and off frequently. Since the MOSFET is effectively dissipating the energy stored in the capacitive load, I don't think that's an issue.
7. If the capacitance is large (or you need to switch the load very frequently), you may need a resistor in series with the drain to dissipate the power. At that point, switching speed becomes important. Note that the energy stored in a capacitor is \$ Energy = \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot C \cdot V^2\$.

My overkill approach would probably be to get an isolated DC-DC converter, a digital signal isolator IC (optical or otherwise), and a gate driver. Of course at that point you could also probably use a NFET.